# I want to draw a line where i click , just like when we click on insect in game and the frog tongue grab that insect this is possible in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to draw a line where I click, just like when we click on insect in game and the frog tongue grab that insect this is possible in HTML

```js
$('body').click(function(event) {
  $('#line').stop(true, true).animate({
    left: event.pageX + 'px',
    top: event.pageY + 'px'
  });
});
```

```css
#testing {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-70%);
  z-index: 300;
}

#testing_line {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #222728;
  transition: right 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: right 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: right 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing">
  <span id="testing_line"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want the line to be redrawn every time you click:

```js
// Create a div, which will look like a line
var line = $("<div>");

// You can change the width of the line below
line.css("width", "100px");

//Give it a height of 0, since you don't want the actual div to be visible
line.css("height", "0px");

// Give the div a black border (this is the actual line we can see.
//You can change the thickness, color, and type of the line below
line.css("border-top", "2px solid black");

// Set the "position" property of the line to "absolute", so that we can easily move it
line.css("position", "absolute");

// Create a callback for the click event
var onClick = function (event) {
    // Make the line start right where the user clicks, then append it to "body" so that it's actually visible
    line.css("top", event.clientY).css("left", event.clientX).appendTo($("body"));
};

// Create the event handler for window
$(window).on("click", onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or try this if you want a new line to be drawn on every click:

```js
//We begin by creating the line div, just like with the first snippet

var line = $("<div>");

line.css("width", "100px");
line.css("height", "0px");
line.css("border-top", "2px solid black");
line.css("position", "absolute");

var onClick = function (event) {

    //Here lies the difference. As you can see, we are not appending the actual line to the body, we are actually making a copy of it and appending that every time the user clicks
    var newLine = line.clone();
    newLine.css("top", event.clientY).css("left", event.clientX).appendTo($("body"));
};

$(window).on("click", onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want one end of the line should be fixed and when i click anywhere on the screen the line expand to that place.

Comment: @Alamgir I'm not sure you can do that with plain HTML. I think there's a library for that. It's called P5.js

Comment: @Alamgir This the link to the documentation: https://p5js.org/reference/

Comment: I think this library will help me Thank you Sir

Comment: @Alamgir I'm glad it helps